# How to compile OBB data associated with an APK, into one OBB file?

Tags: installation, apk, app-data

I downloaded a game from some website, not Play Store. The download consists of two files, namely an APK (StarFront: Collision HD) and data/cache files (OBB), but the OBB is a bunch of loose files that still needs to be compiled into one.

How can I compile it into one OBB file? (Alternatively, how can I install an APK manually which needs OBB file?)

Here's the link: http://pdalife.ru/starfront-collision-hd-android-a2738.html
It's in Russian though, use google translate. I'm not quite positive about what kinda answer it'd be that's why I came to you

Comment: It'd be better if you could provide the link to the download page, so we can experiment with it.

Comment: @MatthewRead I'd say this is a borderline question, but it's not addressed clearly; the problem is related to manual installation of APK which needs OBB, which is relevant to end-user. If the answer is related to programming, then I agree it should be closed as off-topic. Perhaps, it's unclear at the moment, so I hope for the clarification from the OP.